# Навесить плагин с помощью jQuery на элемент после его появления в DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

Всех приветствую!

Проблема выглядит так: нужно отследить появление новых элементов (блок `<div>`) и применять к ним плагин после появления. Блоки одинаковые, появляются по кнопке "Добавить".
Может, с помощью делегирования можно, или отследить появление элемента на странице, или приход post-ответа, или ещё как-то?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery API **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(".parent").on("click", "div", function() {
  $(this).activateYourPlugin();
});
```

Где `.parent` — это родительский блок (неизменяемый AJAX'ом), содержащий ваши дивы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я думал о похожем решении, но меня смущает событие click. Будет ли оно поставлено в очередь и гарантированно вешать плагин, ведь click на кнопку "Добавить" происходит чуть раньше, чем приходит ответ Ajax? И ещё вопрос, я правильно понимаю, в предложенном примере событие нажатия на любой <div> в контейнере parеnt() обрабатывается?

Comment: Да, попробовал - не успевает, срабатывает до обновления.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ обычно такое используется вроде бы.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел - выглядит похожим на то, что нужно. Но не работает. ) В браузере можно увидеть POST запрос и ответ на него, но поймать по URL почему-то не получается. Срабатывает только при загрузке страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда будет срабатывать и даже на новых элементах

```
$(document).on("click", ".parent div", function() {
  $(this).activateYourPlugin();
});
```